# Apply this "folder only" permissions for AD Groups to a folder

Tags: c#, directory, permissions, active-directory, file-permissions

I'm struggling a bit with folder permissions.

I want to basically add a AD group to a folder with modify access but then restrict it.

Problem is I couldn't figure out how to apply a permission to
"this folder only"

The goal is to set the following restrictions to a main folder:

- deny delete subfolders
- deny delete
- deny change permissions
- deny take ownership

[image: Here is a picture of the windows GUI]

I found the AccessRule Class but I can't find any detail on how to do this with C#

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please read "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: Anyone a Idea or a bit of help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
Here is the code and the info:

```
//set params for all access sets
AccessControlType DenyAccess = AccessControlType.Deny;
AccessControlType AllowAccess = AccessControlType.Allow;
InheritanceFlags inheritFlag = InheritanceFlags.None;
InheritanceFlags inheritFlag2 = InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit;
InheritanceFlags inheritFlag3 = InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit;
PropagationFlags propagationFlags = PropagationFlags.None;
FileSystemRights access = FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions;
FileSystemRights access2 = FileSystemRights.Delete;
FileSystemRights access3 = FileSystemRights.TakeOwnership;
FileSystemRights access4 = FileSystemRights.DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles;
FileSystemRights ReadAccess = FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute;
FileSystemRights ModifyAccess = FileSystemRights.Modify;

DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(strPath);
DirectorySecurity security = info.GetAccessControl();

//set read right for group
NTAccount GroupRead = new NTAccount(StrDomain, strGroupRead);
security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(GroupRead, ReadAccess, inheritFlag2, propagationFlags, AllowAccess));
security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(GroupRead, ReadAccess, inheritFlag3, propagationFlags, AllowAccess));

//set Modify right for group
NTAccount GroupModify = new NTAccount(StrDomain, strGoupModify);
security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(GroupModify, ModifyAccess, inheritFlag2, propagationFlags, AllowAccess));
security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(GroupModify, ModifyAccess, inheritFlag3, propagationFlags, AllowAccess));

//set special right group
security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(groupModify, access, inheritFlag, propagationFlags, DenyAccess)); //ChangePermission
security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(groupModify, access2, inheritFlag, propagationFlags, DenyAccess)); //Delete
security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(groupModify, access3, inheritFlag, propagationFlags, DenyAccess)); //Ownership
security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(groupModify, access4, inheritFlag, propagationFlags, DenyAccess)); //Delete subfiles and folders

//add rights to folder
info.SetAccessControl(security);
```

This gives you a folder with a read and modify group and the modify group can't delete the main folder and also the members can't take ownership  over it nor change the permissions on it.

cheers